# Adding a file through Django shell

Tags: django

Django 1.11.6

I am trying to save a file through Django shell. Could you have a look at the traceback and tell me what I do wrongly?

**Model:**

```
class ItemFile(ChecksumMixin,
               models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item,
                             on_delete=models.PROTECT,
                             verbose_name=_("item"))


    file = models.FileField(blank=False,
                            max_length=255,
                            upload_to=get_item_path,
                            verbose_name=_("file"))
```

**In the shell:**

```
from django.core.files import File
f = File('/home/michael/PycharmProjects/photoarchive_4/general/static/test/text_1.pdf', 'rb')
i = Item.objects.get(pk=1)

ItemFile.objects.create(item=i, file=f)
```

**Traceback:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/michael/PycharmProjects/venv/photoarchive_4/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1059, in <listcomp>
    for obj in self.query.objs
  File "/home/michael/PycharmProjects/venv/photoarchive_4/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1058, in <listcomp>
    [self.prepare_value(field, self.pre_save_val(field, obj)) for field in fields]
  File "/home/michael/PycharmProjects/venv/photoarchive_4/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1008, in pre_save_val
    return field.pre_save(obj, add=True)
  File "/home/michael/PycharmProjects/venv/photoarchive_4/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/files.py", line 296, in pre_save
    file.save(file.name, file.file, save=False)
  File "/home/michael/PycharmProjects/venv/photoarchive_4/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/files.py", line 94, in save
    self.name = self.storage.save(name, content, max_length=self.field.max_length)
  File "/home/michael/PycharmProjects/venv/photoarchive_4/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/files/storage.py", line 54, in save
    return self._save(name, content)
  File "/home/michael/PycharmProjects/venv/photoarchive_4/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/files/storage.py", line 351, in _save
    for chunk in content.chunks():
  File "/home/michael/PycharmProjects/venv/photoarchive_4/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/files/base.py", line 81, in chunks
    data = self.read(chunk_size)
  File "/home/michael/PycharmProjects/venv/photoarchive_4/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/files/utils.py", line 16, in <lambda>
    read = property(lambda self: self.file.read)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Django `File` class expects a Python `file` object, not a path/filename:

```
f = File(open('/home/…/text_1.pdf', 'rb'))
```

Django docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/files/#the-file-object (also see the note on closing opened files)